# Match array value to a part of a string

Tags: php

I got an array and a string. I want to match the string to any part of the array values and add the matching values into `$newAr`

```
$mood = array('orange', 'blue', 'green', 'red', 'pink', 'brown', 'black');
$str = "re";
$newAr = array();
```

How can I get all array values which has the `$str` value anywhere in it into the new array `$newAr`?

I'm expecting:

```
$newAr[] = array('green')
$newAr[] = array('red')
```

I tried `if (stripos($mood, $str) !== false) { }` but does not do what I expect.

Comment: You've got the right idea, but you'll need [`array_filter()`](http://php.net/array-filter) to go through your array and find matches. Remember to add `use ($str)` when defining the callback (eg. `function($item) use ($str)`) so that you can actually use that search term variable inside the callback.

Comment: It would be: `array_filter($mood, function($e) use ($str) {
    return stripos($e, $str) !== false;
});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one simple way:

```
$newAr = preg_grep("/$str/", $mood);
```

If you want it case-insensitive, for example `RE`, `re`, `Re` or `rE` then use the `i` modifier `"/$str/i"`.

To have a multi-dimensional array as you show, it would be easy with `array_map()`:

```
$newAr = array_map(function($v) { return (array)$v; }, $newAr);
```

Or from your comment to key with `match`:

```
$newAr = array_map(function($v) { return array('match'=>$v); }, $newAr);
```

To get the JSON format that you are expecting you would need to re-index the array:

```
echo json_encode(array_values($newAr));
```

So to put it all together:

```
$newAr = array_values(array_map(function($v) {
                                   return array('match'=>$v);
                                },
                                preg_grep("/$str/i", $mood)));
```

And after all of that, this would have been simpler:

```
foreach($mood as $value) {
    if(stripos($value, $str) !== false) {
        $newAr[] = array('match'=>$value);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice. +10 But what happens if `$str = "AB"`?

Comment: I use json_encod to echo values. I usually add values as `$newAr[] = array('match'=>$val["student"]);` so the output is `[{"match":"Roy"},{"match":"Rose"}]`. How can I do `preg_grep("/$str/", $mood)` and still maintain the output format?

Comment: Wow! thanks. :) WHen I did your suggestion the output was not as expected. e.g. `[{"match":"Roy"},{"match":"Rose"},{"1":{"match":"Red"}}]`. Instead of `$newAr =` i use `$newAr[] =` bcause I add multple values to $newAr array.

Comment: I want it to be like `[{"match":"Roy"},{"match":"Rose"},{"match":"Red"}]`

Comment: Last edit.  This evolved so much a loop is probably easier.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple script:

```
$mood = array('orange', 'blue', 'green', 'red', 'pink', 'brown', 'black');
$str = "re";
$matches = array_filter($mood, function($var) use ($str) { return preg_match("/$str/i", $var); });

print_r($matches);
```

Result:

```
Array ( [2] => green [3] => red )
```

Comment: Oh why in the world would you use a `preg_match_all` or even `preg_match` inside the `array_filter` callback?